# Inserting to head and tail of a doubly linked list -- only prints out last tail item inserted

Tags: c, insert, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a doubly linked list in order to study for an exam and am running into some trouble when inserting items into the tail -- it prints out correctly when I only insert to the head in the list. However, when I insert to the tail in the list only the last tail item is printed out. Below is my full code:

```
 /*
    - Q2: Write a function that takes a LinkedList struct pointer and inserts at the head of the linked list. 

    - Q3. Write a function that takes a LinkedList struct pointer and frees all memory associated with it. (
          For a solution, see fancy-linked-lists.c, attached above.) 

    - Q4  Review all the functions from today's code and give their big-oh runtimes.

    - Q5:  Implement  functions for doubly linked lists: 
        -  tail_insert(), 
        -  head_insert(), 
        -  tail_delete(), 
        -  head_delete(), 
        -  delete_Nth(). 
        -  Repeat these exercises with doubly linked lists in which you maintain a tail pointer.
        -  How does the tail pointer affect the runtimes of these functions?
        -  Are any of these functions more efficient for doubly linked lists with tail pointers than they are for singly linked lists with tail pointers?
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *next;
   struct node *prev;
} node;

node *createNode(int data)
{
    node *ptr = NULL;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("space could not be allocated\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    ptr->prev = NULL;

    return ptr;
}

node *tailInsert(node *head, int data)
{
        if(head->next == NULL)
    {
        node *temp;
        temp = createNode(data);
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev = head;
        head->next = temp;
        return head;
    }
    tailInsert(head->next, data);
}

node *frontInsert(node *head, int data)
{
    node *newHead;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        return createNode(data);
    }

    newHead = createNode(data);
    newHead->next = head;
    newHead->prev = NULL;

    return newHead;
}

node *destroy_linked_list(node *list)
{
    /*if (list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Free the entire list within this struct.
    destroy_list(list->head);

    // Free the struct itself.
    free(list);

    return NULL;
    */
}

void printList(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty List\n");
        return;
    }

    for(; head != NULL; head = head->next)
        printf("%d ", head->data);

    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    node *head = NULL;

    head = frontInsert(head, 1);
    head = frontInsert(head, 2);
    head = frontInsert(head, 3);
    head = tailInsert(head, 4);
    head = tailInsert(head, 5);
    head = tailInsert(head, 6);

    printList(head);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: You are returning the temp(last node) and assigning to head in tailInsert function

Comment: `return tailInsert(head->next, data);` --> `tailInsert(head->next, data);
    return head;` or `node *tailInsert(node *head, int data)` --> `void  tailInsert(node *head, int data)`

Comment: Also `frontInsert` needs `head->prev = newHead;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you, the first way did not work, however, the second one worked :).

Comment: first [DEMO](http://ideone.com/rHD8uY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the temp(last node) from tailInsert and assigning to head. Do not change the head pointer if you are inserting at tail.

```
void tailInsert(node *head, int data)
{
    if(head->next == NULL)
    {
      node *temp;
      temp = createNode(data);
      temp->next = NULL;
      temp->prev = head;
      head->next = temp;
      return ;
    }
    tailInsert(head->next, data);
}
```

In main do not assign anything to head if you are calling `tailInsert` function

Comment: I updated it to return the head, however, it only prints the last two values now. I'm confused because the code was identical other than the pointer to the previous node to my singly linked list that worked perfectly fine.

Comment: You have used recursion. The head node during the last recursive call would be the tail node.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.